# Функция обратного отсчета

Tags: python, django

У меня есть следующий класс с функцией:

```
class DateClass(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def date_iteration():
        start_date = self.date_start
        end_date = start_date + timedelta(self.date_end - self.date_start)
        datesAndRoute = [] 
        for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
            dateURL = single_date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            get_url = request_url_generate(dateURL)
            datesAndRoute.append(get_url)
         return datesAndRoute
```

Пользователь вводит значения дат: начало и конец. Нужно что-то вроде таймера на странице:

> осталось "Х" дней.

Как вывести это в template?
Можно ли сделать так: вводится только начальная дата `date_start`, а к конечной дате автоматически прибавляется 30 дней, также из функции требуется передать полученное значение в поле `date_end`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Для начала создайте *форму*, где пользователь будет вводить *начальную* и *конечную* дату, а там уже или отдавайте данные на *сервер* (можно *аяксом*) и обрабатывайте их, или сразу на *js* обрабатывайте их.
2. Можно, использовать сигналы, или переопределить функцию `save`
3. Как Вы собрались передавать список в поле `DateField`?

Comment: 1. Зачем форма? Данные вводятся с админки 3. Я не собиралась передавать список в DateField, а имела ввиду можно ли (необязательно с датой, а вообще): а) вводим значение первого поля б) в функции вычисляется значение второго поля в) полученное значение записывается во второе поле. И кстати как вообще вывести функцию в шаблон?

Comment: 1. Что же вы сразу не говорите, что речь идёт об админке? Тогда переписывайте шаблон админки и юзайте скрипты. 3. Можно (см. пункт 2). Вывести функцию в шаблон нельзя. Результат работы функции - можно.